# sympy accessing and using solver data

Tags: python, sympy

I just started with SymPy and I have a very basic question: How can I access and use the data from an obtained solution? Below I attach a possible problem. I would like to use the results "5.725" and "0.725" as data for other operations. I tried to access it by giving a name to the solve operation, such as a=solve...and then access a[0] and a[1] as if it were a list, but it doesn't seem to work. Any clue? Thanks in advance!

```
F=[-6.45,0,0] 
F1=[x,0,0]
F2=[y,0,0]
M=[0,0,10]
d1_F1=[0,0,-2*F1[0]]
d2_F2=[0,0,2*F2[0]]

solve([Matrix(F)+Matrix(F1)+Matrix(F2),Matrix(M)+Matrix(d1_F1)+Matrix(d2_F2)],[x,y])

{x:5.725,y:0.725}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the results of `solve` back as a dictionary.  You can access the numbers by using the variables as keys to index into it.  For example:

```
>>> sol = solve([Matrix(F)+Matrix(F1)+Matrix(F2),Matrix(M)+Matrix(d1_F1)+Matrix(d2_F2)],[x,y])
>>> sol
{x: 5.72500000000000, y: 0.725000000000000}
>>> sol[x]
5.72500000000000
>>> sol[y]
0.725000000000000
```

You may want to look at the [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) section of the Python tutorial.

Comment: ...It had to be easy! Thank you very much for your reply!